# Is there a way to configure bash or pass so that `pass otp pass-name` commands will tab complete like regular `pass pass-name` commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I can use the tab key to auto-complete a `pass pass-name` command, but no such auto-complete is happening when trying the same with a `pass otp pass-name` command.

Is there some configuration that I need to apply, or is this just not possible?

Using pass v1.7.4 and pass otp v1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can enable bash completion for `pass otp` by sourcing its completion file:

`source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/pass-otp`

To have the completion loaded automatically you can add the above line to your shell initialization file, `~/.bashrc` for example.

---

The above configuration should not be necessary if you have bash-completion package installed and bash completion enabled (usually by sourcing `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`). However, given completion for pass itself works, this should be already the case. There's seemingly a bug in the bash completion scripts shipped - I observe the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04.2, pass 1.7.4-5, pass-extension-otp 1.2.0-2 and bash-completion 1:2.11-5ubuntu1.

There's [a bug report](https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp/issues/137) for the issue.